# how to avoid api calls on default 'should create' method

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

ng-cli generates some default tests for me when i create a component using angular cli. But this tests fails intermittently on my jenkins.

Here are some more details:

## example.component.ts

```
ngOnit(){
   this.get1stData();
   this.get2ndData();
}

get1stData(){
  this.service.get1stData().subscribe()....
}

get2ndData(){
 this.service.get2ndData().subscribe()....
}
```

## example.component.spec.ts

```
  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(NamespaceHomeComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    service = TestBed.get(service);
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });
  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
```

This simple tests failed if the there is some issue with the api. How can I avoid calling the api here.

I get this error:

```
  {
    "message": "An error was thrown in afterAll\nUncaught [object Object] thrown",
    "str": "An error was thrown in afterAll\nUncaught [object Object] thrown"
  }
```

Comment: Mock your dependencies ? It should already be done in your tests ...

Comment: sorry but I am new to this unit test... not sure how i can mock it... i just added beforeEach method for unit test

Comment: Well you have a [very comprehensive documentation](https://angular.io/guide/testing), you should start reading it before trying testing on your own !

Comment: That test you have above should not fail. If it does it either fails because you have not defined your dependencies so they can't be injected **and/or** it fails because you have business logic in the constructor of your component like calling a service method.